# I am Implementing Static Methods for Dealing with Conversions from and to UTC - Is this Unnecessary?

Tags: c#

So I absolutely want to store DateTimeOffset objects in UTC format. To achieve the correct conversations, I've created my own methods to deal with the conversions.

```
/// <summary>String representation of the specified time zone.</summary>
        private const String LOCAL_TIME_ZONE_STRING_REPRESENTATION = "GMT Standard Time";
        /// <summary>TimeZoneInfo representation of the specified time zone.</summary>
        private static TimeZoneInfo LOCAL_TIME_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(LOCAL_TIME_ZONE_STRING_REPRESENTATION);

        /// <summary>With a given DateTime, passed DateTime is assumed it has been parsed and shares the same time zone as TimeZoneInfo LOCAL_TIME_ZONE.</summary>
        /// <param name="dateAndTime">DateTime in TimeZoneInfo LOCAL_TIME_ZONE.</param>
        /// <returns>UTC DateTime.</returns>
        public static DateTime ConvertToUtcDateTime(DateTime dateAndTime)
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateAndTime, LOCAL_TIME_ZONE).ToUniversalTime();
        }
        /// <summary>With a given DateTime, the DateTime is assumed to be a UTC time. It will then return a DateTime converted to TimeZoneInfo LOCAL_TIME_ZONE.</summary>
        /// <param name="dateAndTime">DateTime that is in UTC.</param>
        /// <returns>Converted to TimeZoneInfo LOCAL_TIME_ZONE DateTime.</returns>
        public static DateTime ConvertToLocalDateTime(DateTime dateAndTime)
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateAndTime, LOCAL_TIME_ZONE);
        }
```

Using the String constant LOCAL_TIME_ZONE_STRING_REPRESENTATION, any user who wishes to compile the code can specify which time zone they want the code to run in, rather than it try to use Window's local time zone.

Then the two above methods can be used to make a conversion between between the two:

```
private static void Main()
        {
            //Parse a date and time. It is to be assumed this parsed date and time is in the same time zone
            // as LOCAL_TIME_ZONE.
            DateTimeOffset dateTime = ConvertToUtcDateTime(new DateTime(2019,6,1,15,30,0));

            //Assuming we have retrieved a date and time that is in UTC time, we can now convert it
            // to the same time zone as LOCAL_TIME_ZONE.
            DateTime convertedFromUTC = ConvertToLocalDateTime(dateTime.DateTime);
}
```

The system would be able to parse DateTime's that have no time zone associated with them regardless where they would've came from, and convert them into UTC time assuming that DateTime came from the same TimeZone as LOCAL_TIME_ZONE. The only time where we would need to convert retrieved UTC DateTimes back into the same time zone as LOCAL_TIME_ZONE would be when we are visually displaying it to a user. All TimeSpan calculations etc, would use the UTC DateTimeOffset.

This seems to work as intended, and I can change LOCAL_TIME_ZONE_STRING_REPRESENTATION to any time zone I want, and using the methods I created, the system uses that time zone instead of Window's local time zone.

This would be particularly useful for me as the server hosting an application may be in a different time zone and have a different culture, but its intended users could be for a totally different time zone.

Am I making too much work for myself, or would this be a reasonable way to implement what I need?

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for the CodeReview site

Comment: Ah I didn't know there was a CodeReview sub domain. Should I post it there instead?

Comment: Its hard to say, those cats can be pretty picky too. Maybe check out the site, and check out the help and see if you think it might get a better response

Comment: Hmm, logically, this is half a code review and half a genuine C# programming question!